# Automatically Grow a View's Height Based on It's Content

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, uistackview

## Situation

I have a (vertical) `UIStackView` containing both a plain `UIView` of height `50` (named `sliderView`) and a `UILabel` of height `36` defined in my storyboard. The label's `alpha` property is initially set to `0.0` to make it invisible.

In the controller's `viewDidLoad` I use UIViewController Containment to add another view controller's view to as a subview of `sliderView`. This new subview does not necessarily match `sliderViews` height. It might actually a fair bit taller.

At first, this setup looks fine. Once I make the label visible, I see that it still starts at a y-position of `50`. So, the `sliderView` did not automatically stretch to use it's new child's height. Makes sense.

## Question

I thought that I could easily just call `sizeToFit` on `sliderView` to make those two heights fit. Unfortunately, this does not seem to work. Am I misunderstanding something here? Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Use following method to get the `CGSize` required for `NSString` text.

```
- (CGSize)getHeightForText:(NSString *)text havingWidth:(CGFloat)widthValue andFont:(UIFont *)font {
CGSize size = CGSizeZero;
if (text) {
    CGRect frame = [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(widthValue, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName:font } context:nil];
    size = CGSizeMake(frame.size.width, frame.size.height+20.0f);
}
return size;
}
```

Here `width` parameter is the width of your `label` and `font` is the font specified for your `label`. Call `CGSize.height` to get the height.

Comment: Well, thanks for the reply, but that's not what I'm looking for. The label is perfectly fine. I need to resize the `sliderView`.